# Inelastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

I'm solving a problem that reads

> "Two cars collide with masses $m_1=m_2=140\,$kg with perpendicular velocities $v_1=3.6\,$m/s and $v_2=7.2\,$m/s. After the collision they keep going at a common velocity $v_3.$ Calculate $v_3$.”

Now I used the momentum formula and arrive at $v_3 = \frac{m_1v_1+m_2v_2}{m_1+m_2}$ which gives me $5.4\,$m/s. However the solutions also say the formula above but then in the next step the formula changes to $v_3 = \frac{\sqrt{m_1^2v_1^2+m_2^2v_2^2}}{m_1+m_2}.$ Why did they square the masses and velocity and root the sum? I've also solved these types of problems in the past and the first equation I wrote worked just fine. Does it have to do with the fact the collision is at an angle or is it for another reason?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where using proper vector notation makes your problem much clearer.

Before the collision, your system's total momentum is

\begin{align}
\vec p_0 &= \vec p_1 + \vec p_2
&
\text{with}\quad \vec p_1 &= m_1 v_1 \hat x
\\ && \text{and}\quad \vec p_2 &= m_2 v_2 \hat y
\end{align}

Your inelastic collision doesn't change the total momentum, so the final momentum is also

\begin{align}
\vec p_3 &= \vec p_1 + \vec p_2
\\ & = m_1 v_1 \hat x + m_2 v_2 \hat y
\\ & = p_x \hat x + p_y \hat y
\end{align}

Since the two components are perpendicular, the magnitude of the final component is

$$
\left|\vec p\right| = \sqrt{
(p_x)^2 + (p_y)^2
}
$$

You can expand this into your expression for $v_3 = \frac{p}{m_1+m_2}$ if you are confident in your algebra skills.

If you are trying to solve these problems by memorizing "the formulas," you'll be stymied when you run across a situation that is just barely different from what you've encountered before. If you can remember *how you get to* the formulas you know, then you can follow those rules to come up with your own solutions to novel problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a collision at perpendicular directions, the first formula i think is not applicable here.

The second formula is correct, i think, and here is how i arrived at it:

[image]

In the x direction, according to momentum conservation, m2 v2= (m1+m2) v3x. In the y direction, accoridng to momentum conservation, m1 v1= (m1+m2) v3y. This way one can get v3x, v3y.

Then one get v3 using $v3 = \sqrt{v3x^2+v3y^2}$. After plugging in v3x, v3y from above, one get
$$v3=\sqrt{\frac{m2^2 v2^2}{(m1+m2)^2}+\frac{m1^2 v1^2}{(m1+m2)^2}}$$
which is just
$ \sqrt{m2^2 v2^2+m1^2 v1^2}/(m1+m2)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that this is an example of the use of Pythagoras to equate the vector sum of the initial momenta $m\vec v_1$ and $m\vec v_1$ to the final momentum $m\vec v_2$ producing $m\,v_1^2+ m\,v_2^2 = m\,v_3^2$.

However you might have found it strange that

$m_1v_1+m_2v_2 = \sqrt{m_1^2v_1^2+m_2^2v_2^2}$, ie $(m_1v_1+m_2v_2)^2 = m_1^2v_1^2+m_2^2v_2^2$?

The reason is to be found by realising that vectors are involved and a dot product is involved.

$(m_1\vec v_1+m_2\vec v_2)^2 = (m_1\vec v_1)\cdot(m_1\vec v_1)+2(m_1\vec v_1)\cdot(m_2\vec v_2)+(m_2\vec v_2)\cdot(m_2\vec v_2)$.

The middle term has the dot product $v_1\cdot v_2$  which is zero because the initial velocities are orthogonal.